# 2-term silting objects in algebras of global dimension at most 2

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $P$ be a 2-term silting complex (see defintion 2.1 in https://ntnuopen.ntnu.no/ntnu-xmlui/bitstream/handle/11250/2639675/survey_revised14042019.pdf?sequence=1 )in a finite dimensional algebra $A$ of global dimension $\leq 2$ and $B$ the endomorphism ring of $P$ and $X$ an indecomposable $B$-module.

> Question: Is it true that the injective dimension of $X$ is $\leq 3$ or the projective dimension of $X$ is $\leq 3$?

Note that this would imply that the global dimension of $B$ is $\leq 7$, which was proven in https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10468-017-9709-9.

Comment: Can you clarify which definition of the silting object you have in mind? There are at least three non-equivalent ones.

Comment: @DenisT I added a reference.